# Mirror a line segment

Tags: geometry, line, mirroring

I have a line segment (x1, y1), (x2, y2) that i need "mirrored" so the new line becomes perpendicular to the first one and passes through its middle.

The line segment (0,0),(2,2) should return a new line segment (0,2),(2,0)

Can anyone help me with a function/formula to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The midpoint is (mx,my) = ((x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2).

To rotate the endpoints 90 degrees about the middle, first compute a vector:

```
(dx,dy) = (x1-mx),(y1-my)
```

then rotate it 90 degrees:

```
dx1 = -dy
dy1 = dx
```

Then the new point becomes:

```
x1 = mx+dx1
y1 = my+dy1
```

Repeat for x2,y2.

You may also combine steps if you're careful.

Comment: I ended up using this solution, as it was that much simpler. I will try to read up on scaling matrixes too, but that will be when no deadlines are nagging me...

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for a symmetry. 
well, a good way of doing that could be using a [scaling matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_%28geometry%29).

[image: scaling_matrix]

vx, vy, vz are the coefficient of scaling. px,py,pz are the coordinate of a point. If you multiply the scale matrix for the point coordinate, you will get the scaled coordinates of that point.

A scaling matrix with vx=vy=vz= 1 is an identity transform.
For obtain a mirror effect you could simply invert the matrix coefficient of the axis on which you want to perform the symmetry.

For example :

```
1  0 0|px

0 -1 0|py

0  0 1|pz
```

will calculate the symmetric point of the given vector respect to y axis.

Comment: Thats something i have never used before, but i will take your word for it and get my reading glasses. The wiki page suprisingly didnt help all that much, too bad, those are usually fairly useful.